# Attribute List for ASP.Net controls not showing in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005

In Visual Studio 2005 in the html source view, the attribute list that drops down showing you all available properties of an ASP.Net server control is not showing for me.  I have to manually type in each attribute name with no list to choose from.

I have been unable to find a setting that turns this on and off.  I have reset my Visual Studio settings back to the default and it still is not working.

Update: Later I realized that the asp controls are also not listed in the context menu drop down that appears when you start typing in the source view.  Other HTML controls are showing in the context menu.  I also get the attributes to drop down for the html controls.  So my issue appears to be related to not getting the asp tags in the list in the source view.  Also, in design view, my toolbox was only showing html controls.  I reset my toolbox and now all sections appear however the controls in the common controls section are disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

1. Go to Tools->Options menu.
2. Pick Text Editor -> File Extesion fom a tree at the left part of Options dialog.
3. Type ascx (or the file type that intellisense doesnt show) in Extesion text box.
4. Select User Control Editor from Editor dropdown.
5. Click Add and then Ok to close dialog and re-open your files.

Comment: This did not work.  Also, I have a different computer with VS 2005 that does not have the problem and there are no file extension mappings under that dialog.

Comment: so, i think it is better to reinstall VS.